# Why don't my shorthand functions for document.querySelector work as expected?

Tags: typescript

I wrote many shorthand functions for `document.querySelector` but I faced many issues regarding type inference in *Typescript* :

```
const $ = document.querySelector; // 1
const $ = (selector: string) => document.querySelector(selector); // 2
const $ = (selector: keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap) => document.querySelector(selector); // 3
```

No `$` value is the equivalent of `document.querySelector`.

The first one throws an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: 'querySelector' called on an object that does not implement interface Document.

The second one doesn't consider HTML element's tag name. Example:

```
const textarea = $("textarea"); 
       ^ Element | null
const textarea2 = document.querySelector("textarea");
        ^ HTMLTextAreaElement | null
```

The third one doesn't solve the issue of the second one as well:

```
const textarea = $("textarea"); 
       ^ HTMLObjectElement | HTMLElement | HTMLAnchorElement | HTMLAreaElement | HTMLAudioElement | ... 58 more ... | null
const textarea2 = document.querySelector("textarea");
        ^ HTMLTextAreaElement | null
```

What is the issue on all my shorthand functions' signatures? What if I want the equivalent for `document.querySelectorAll`, like this?

```
const $$ = document.querySelectorAll;
```

Comment: The error from your first approach is because you're not calling on any object anymore. Any success with `const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document)`?

Comment: The first one has good old `this`/binding issues! @CollinD's solution works for that _functionally_, but loses the typings. This should work: `const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document) as Document["querySelector"]`.

Comment: The second doesn't infer anything from the input, as the type is simply `string`, so it gives the broadest output possible. The third is a narrow version that only allows selecting by tag name, but still doesn't utilize the actual type to narrow the output.

Comment: If that answers your question, I can write up a proper answer?

Comment: Thanks for replying, indeed it resolves my issue. I'll accept the answer if you write one.